# Firebase DocumentSnapshot with Promises getting undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that gets a document collection, then iterates over the collection of returned documents looking up additional data. This is done in a `forEach` loop, adding the document to an array returning `Promise.all(array)`.

From here I can chain another `then(snapshot => { })` to get the items in the array returned from the Promise, however the problem is when I invoke the method `data()` to get a plain old javascript object it's always returning `undefined`.  I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Here's the Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
exports.cloudFunctionApi = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
   admin.firestore().collection("myDocuments").get()
   .then(snapshot => {
      const promises = []
      snapshot.forEach(item => {
         if(item.id == "abc123") {
            const data = item.data()
            const p = admin.firestore().doc(`myDocumentDetail/${item.id}`).get()
            promises.push(p)
         }
      })
      return Promise.all(promises)
   })
   .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(item => {
         const data = item.data()
         console.log(`data is:  ${data}`)   // <- data is undefined
      })
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
   })
})
```

I was getting some dumb warnings about `const promises = []` which I resolved in tsconfig.json file, the settings are:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "outDir": "lib",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
       "src"
     ],
     "strictNullChecks":false
}
```

Comment: The "dumb warnings" you're referring to are TypeScript's way of telling you that you lost type information about your promises with the way it was declared.  Correcting warning that without disabling the strict checking would help the readability of your code, and the typesafety of the code after it.  `const promises: Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>[] = []`

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for replying.  I get the swiggely lines under my declaration of `promises` when I add `"strict": true` to my tsconfig.json file.  Love to know what the best approach\configuration I should using here.

By the way, isn't always the way, I removed the document that was causing the `undefined` and added it back again. Problem solved!  

Answer (score 1):

When [data()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) returns undefined, according to the linked API documentation, that means the document you requested with `get()` doesn't exist.  Since we can't see your data, or any of the variables in your code, you're going to have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.

I suggest putting a check for `data.exists` in your code so you can find out if the requested document exists before calling `data()`, or simply checking the result of `data()` before trying to act on it.

Answer (score 0):

Murphy's law, as soon as you post a question you figure out the answer.

In `tsconfig.json` I added `"strict": true` and for the declaration of my array, I changed the code to be `const promises:any[] = []`.  This was the only way I could resolve the "dumb error", but as Doug Stevenson posted, you could also use `const promises: Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot>[] = []` for typesafety.

Next I removed the document from the collection and re-added it back with the same document identifier.  Sure enough, I'm no longer seeing `undefined` but instead the full object representation. Yah!